# Should I keep the server code and the client-code of an application in the same git directory?

Tags: git, svn, web-applications, github

I'm making a game that will function as a web app, and I have some server code, and some client code. Both of these are in their own, separate directories, and then they're wrapped up into a git directory, which is pushed to Github. Does this way of doing things have any flaws, and should I create separate git directories for the same project?

Comment: Do you want to say you have some webapp and a local executable, Two separated projects?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, @AmitRanjan.

Comment: for example, take yahoo messenger... to chat on it, we use yahoo messenger executable installed on our pc that connects to some other application/service on yahoo server. So here ,yahoo uses two different tools for chat, one at the server end and another at the client end (our end). Is yours, the same scenario???  Anyways, see my answer below.

Comment: Yes, I have the Javascript code and HTML for the client, and the Javascript code for the server.

Comment: I want two say,whether they are two different projects or you have placed in a single file. Better I would suggest, go for single repository for Single Project,no matter what type of project it is..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "git directory" you mean a single git-controlled tree of subdirectories, yes that's fine.   Certainly do not use separate git repositories for the client and the server, otherwise you will have to design a scheme for checking protocol-version consistency when a client connects to a server (though you may have other reasons to need to support this, for example any time the client and server are pacakged or deployed separately you would need to do this).

However, if you actually mean filesystem directory, I would advise not.    Create a subdirectory for the definitions (header files normally) that the client and server would need to share, and keep the client code and server code in two other separate directories.   Unless they're very trivial and there will always in total be a tiny amount of code.

Answer (score 0):

GIT ,SVN is for versioning (version control system).As a dotnet dev,if i have any number of projects in my single solution (whether its a web, dll or exe), i will prefer pushing it in a single reposiotry.